# Given any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can I find an orthogonal matrix $K$ such that $K\beta= \vert \beta \vert \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any $\beta \in  \mathbb{R}^2$(not the zero vector) can I find an orthogonal matrix $K$ such that $K\beta= \vert \beta \vert \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.
I am not sure how do I actually start reasoning about this problem. Even hints would be appreciated

Comment: hints- try to do it for special values of $\beta$, remind yourself what an orthogonal matrix represents geometrically

Comment: I tried to show it for $\beta =(c,0)'$ and $\beta=(0,c)$ and I can find orthogonal matrices in these case. Can I ask you if its true or if I am looking for a counter example

Comment: So we can think of $K$ as a matrix which rotates $\beta$ until it is on the $x$-axis?

Comment: Its true, and yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Look for 
$$K=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$
and write $\beta$ in polar coordinates
$$\beta=\begin{bmatrix}
R\cos(\phi)  \\
R\sin(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}$$